# php function fgetcsv not work for line have \""

Tags: php, csv, fgetcsv

I have data in phpmyadmin, example: (first row is header)

```
||from||to||messages||

||john||andy||meeting now||

||dony||sherly||Place in \"Jakarta\" , Indonesia, 15412
```

when I export to csv via phpmyadmin version 3.5.6, I get this csv file:

```
"from","to","messages"

"john","andy","meeting now"

"from","to","Place in \""Jakarta\"" , Indonesia, 15412"
```

if I use  this code

```
<?php
// code start 

$file = fopen($path, 'r');

while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {

print_r($line);

}

fclose($file);

// code end
?>
```

I hope get this

```
//output start

Array

(

[0] => from

[1] => to

[2] => messages

)

Array

(

[0] => john

[1] => andy

[2] => meeting now

)

Array

(

[0] => dony

[1] => sherly

[2] => Place in \"Jakarta\" , Indonesia, 15412

)

//output end
```

but instead I get

```
//output start

Array

(

[0] => from

[1] => to

[2] => messages

)

Array

(

[0] => john

[1] => andy

[2] => meeting now

)

Array

(

[0] => from

[1] => to

[2] => Place in \"Jakarta\"" 

[3] =>  Indonesia

[4] =>  15412"

)

//output end
```

anyone can help this error?

Comment: Look at the $escape argument for the fgetcsv() function - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Comment: Also maybe at the `$enclosure` argument - http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Comment: Have you tried `stripslashes($line)`.. ??

Answer (score 0):

You have double double quotes.

```
"from","to","Place in \""Jakarta\"" , Indonesia, 15412"
```

should be

```
"from","to","Place in \"Jakarta\" , Indonesia, 15412"
```